# Cause for Undefined symbols for architecture i386?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

what is the true reason for the "Undefined symbols for architecture i386:" errors that occur?

It appears way too often with various libraries...

Regards
Mirza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you need to link with frameworks that are included in the iOS sdk (QuartzCore or CoreData for example). When you're trying to use a class or object of that framework, and you haven't linked it, you're getting the undefined symbols error.

Comment: The undefined symbols error tells you in which file the undefined symbol lives. If you go to that file, most of the time you see some #import statements that tells you the required frameworks ;)